# Is this allowed in C?

Tags: c, syntax, iar

I've written the following line in C.
I want to know if is supported by the language.
it goes like that:

```
char * mode[7] = Config_Msg.DHCP ? "DHCP" : "Static";
```

Basically I want to insert into mode the String value of "DHCP" or "STATIC", depended on the value in Config_Msg.DHCP.

When I compile in IAR, I get this warning:

```
Warning[Pe520]: initialization with "{...}" expected for aggregate
```

What does this warning mean ?

Comment: [Initializing Aggregate Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81k8cwsz(VS.71).aspx) should be a good read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning means that the answer to your question is no.  What you are doing can be done at runtime, but it is not valid in an initializer.  Just write:

```
char * mode;

mode = Config_Msg.DHCP ? "DHCP" : "Static";
```

Upon closer inspection, that is not the source of your warning.  You had incorrectly declared mode to be an array of 7 pointers, so the compiler was expecting an initialization of the form:

```
char * mode[ 7 ] = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

(the remaining four entries will be initialized to all zeros).

Comment: Such an initialisation **is** valid for a variable inside a function, though.

Comment: It also follows that one cannot modify the string literal after this or you risk an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: `const char *mode = Config_Msg.DHCP ? "DHCP" : "Static";` is valid for a non-static variable.

Comment: @Greg  I'm pretty sure that is not true, yet gcc --std=c89 --pedantic compiles it just fine.  That is surprising. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Yes, my comment is referring to *this* answer (the one without the character array).

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign strings like that, so you should do it like this:

```
char mode[7];
strcpy(mode,Config_Msg.DHCP ? "DHCP" : "Static");
```

Note that I also corrected your declaration for `mode`. You originally declared an array of pointers.

Alternatively, you could also do it with a pointer:

```
char *mode = Config_Msg.DHCP ? "DHCP" : "Static";
```

Answer (score 1):

Mystical's answer is correct, but if you want to know the **reason** your code can't work, it's a bit more complex. You can use a string literal as an initializer for a `char` array, but like all array objects, string literals in an expression (such as the `?:` expression you're using), except as the operand of the `&` or `sizeof` operators, decay to pointers. The result of your `?:` expression is a pointer, and pointers are not valid initializers for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, `char * mode[7]` should be `char mode[7]` in your example; you're wanting an array of `char`s not an array of `char` *pointers*.

To your question, no you can't do that. You have two choices:

1. Declare `mode` as `char *mode` and make it **point** to `"DHCP"` or `"Static"`
2. Keep `mode` as an array of `char` and **copy** `"DHCP"` or `"Static"` into it.

Note that with the first way your strings will be read-only (ie. stored in the .rodata segment), unlike the second way where they'll be copied into your array and can be modified. However, I don't think that'd be a problem for this example.

Answer (score -2):

You `char *mode[7]` variable is an array of pointers to chars.

And what you ask for is not allowed. But you could code

```
char mode[20];

strncpy(mode, sizeof(mode), Config_Msg.DHCP ? "DHCP" : "Static");
```

**edited addition**

Actually, as others pointed out, `strncpy` is dangerous when the limit has been reached. 
My example should better be

```
char mode[20];
memset (mode, 0, sizeof(mode));
strncpy (mode, sizeof(mode)-1, Config_Msg.DHCP ? "DHCP" : "Static");
```

So the last byte of `mode` remains a zero byte. If you are absolutely sure that the `mode` string can only be `"DHCP"` or `"Static"` you should document that in a comment, and you can declare `mode` to be of the minimal length (7, which is the number of letters in *Static* plus 1) and use just `strcpy`. But imagine that you've got, in a few months, another mode like `"automatic"`. If you did not comment your code, you'll screw yourself.

Even understanding your own code in a few months can be painful. This is why good comments are important.

Comment: -1 for (mis)use of `strncpy`. This function should not be taught; it should be burried.

Comment: I disagree. strncpy is much safer than strcpy. It is strcpy which should never have been invented.

Comment: Except for the part: "Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated."

Comment: `strncpy` is **not** a safe/bounded version of `strcpy`. It's a function for copying data from a C string into a fixed-width `char` array such as the ones used by ancient databases or directory structures, with possible truncation. The BSD `strlcpy` function is what you're looking for, but it's really just a special case of the standard `snprintf` function, which is **the only** string writing function in the standard library you should ever touch (except perhaps `memcpy`).

Comment: `strlcpy` is also troublesome sometimes. It always scans the whole source string to create its return value, so if there's no NUL byte there it'll crash. `strncpy` does not. It has it's uses, as long as you're aware of the limitations. The use in this answer is not a good one.